# AngularJS Issue in ng-repeat data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

### Scenario

I have a repeater using ng-repeat which binds to a array of dynamic/ run time computed values. ( i.e, my array contains fields like  Brokerage: ($scope.BuyValue() + $scope.SellValue())* 0.5/100 ).

### Problem

When i change the value in the input box which has a ng-model , field Broker.Brokerage inside the repeater is not getting refreshed. But i am able to update/bind the fields outside the repeater properly.

### Code

```
<body ng-controller="BrokerController">
<div>
  <div>
    Buy Price   <input type="textbox" ng-model="BuyPrice"/><br/> 
    Sell Price  <input type="textbox" ng-model="SellPrice"/><br/> 
    Quantity    <input type="textbox" ng-model="Quantity"/><br/> 
    Buy Value   {{ BuyValue() }} <br/>
    Sell Value   {{ SellValue() }} <br/>
    Profit   {{ Profit() }} <br/><br/><br/>
    <h4>Brokers</h4>
    <div ng-repeat='Broker in Brokers'>
      Broker Name : <b>{{Broker.BrokerName}}</b>
      Brokerage Amount : <i>{{Broker.Brokerage}}</i>  ({{Broker.BrokerageDetail}})
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <script id="angularjs"  src="js/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
  var App = angular.module('ChooseYourBroker', []);

App.controller("BrokerController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {    
$scope.BuyPrice = 10;
$scope.SellPrice = 20;
$scope.Quantity = 100;
$scope.BuyValue = function(){ return ( $scope.BuyPrice * $scope.Quantity )};
$scope.SellValue = function(){ return ( $scope.SellPrice * $scope.Quantity )};
$scope.Profit = function(){ return ( $scope.SellValue() - $scope.BuyValue() )};
$scope.Brokers = [
    {
        BrokerName: 'Broker one', 
        BrokerageDetail :'0.5% value of Sell Value', 
        Brokerage: $scope.SellValue() * 0.5/100
    },
    {
        BrokerName: 'Broker two',  
        BrokerageDetail :'2% value of Sell Value', 
        Brokerage: $scope.SellValue() * 2/100
    },
    {
        BrokerName: 'Broker three', 
        BrokerageDetail :'1% value of Sell Value',  
        Brokerage: $scope.SellValue() * 1/100
    },
    {
        BrokerName: 'Broker Four', 
        BrokerageDetail :'0.5 % value of Buy Value and Sell Value',  
        Brokerage: ($scope.BuyValue() + $scope.SellValue())* 0.5/100
    }];
  }]);



  </script>
```

Comment: Working Plnk for the above code. -> [http://plnkr.co/edit/pqqUxNvviDARTm3RBz7g](http://plnkr.co/edit/pqqUxNvviDARTm3RBz7g) Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `Brokerage` is calculated once, when it is run. Since you did not make a getter function of it or did not run a watcher, it will not be updated. You have two options:

### Option 1. Make a getter function

JS:

```
{
    BrokerName: 'Broker Four', 
    BrokerageDetail :'0.5 % value of Buy Value and Sell Value',  
    GetBrokerage: function () { return ($scope.BuyValue() + $scope.SellValue())* 0.5/100;}
}
```

HTML:

```
<span ng-bind="Broker.GetBrokerage()"></span>
```

### Option 2. Watch `BuyValue` and `SellValue`, and update `Brokers`.

JS:

```
$scope.$watch("BuyValue()", function () { /*update all the brokers*/ });
$scope.$watch("SellValue()", function () { /*update all the brokers*/ });
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set a `$watch` on `SellValue()` in order to be notified whenever the returned value changes:

```
$scope.$watch('SellValue()',function(newValue){
    for(var i=0;i<$scope.Brokers.length;i++){
        $scope.Brokers[i].Brokerage = ... * newValue; // Calculate the Brokerage
    }
});
```

**Explanation:** The view can bind to model values through the scope. The `Brokers` object is not a view element and so is not bound to anything. A `$watch` is needed when the model wants to be notified in changes to other parts of the model. Otherwise, your `Brokerage` property gets calculated only once during the controller's initial run phase.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/hWaHn/) where I've created a `BrokerageRate` to compute the new Brokerage any time the `SellValue()` changes.

`Broker Four` will need a little more work in that there will need to be another watch on `BuyValue()` as that `Brokerage` property needs to be notified of changes to both values.

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/hWaHn/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

So angularJS ng-model doesn't update primitives.
If you want it to automatically update it would be better to do something like

```
$scope.share={};
$scope.share.BuyPrice = 10;
$scope.share.SellPrice = 20;
$scope.share.Quantity = 100;
```

and change

```
Buy Price   <input type="textbox" ng-model="BuyPrice"/><br/> 
Sell Price  <input type="textbox" ng-model="SellPrice"/><br/> 
Quantity    <input type="textbox" ng-model="Quantity"/><br/>
```

to

```
Buy Price   <input type="textbox" ng-model="share.BuyPrice"/><br/> 
Sell Price  <input type="textbox" ng-model="share.SellPrice"/><br/> 
Quantity    <input type="textbox" ng-model="share.Quantity"/><br/>
```

That way the values of share will automatically update without needing to use $watch or setters and getters. However it will not automatically call function(){ return ( $scope.SellValue() - $scope.BuyValue() )}; again

To do this I would do

```
Buy Price   <input type="textbox" ng-model="share.BuyPrice" ng-change="updatePrices()"/><br/> 
Sell Price  <input type="textbox" ng-model="share.SellPrice" ng-change="updatePrices()"/><br/> 
Quantity    <input type="textbox" ng-model="share.Quantity" ng-change="updatePrices()"/><br/>
```

and

```
$scope.updatePrices=function(){
  $scope.share.BuyValue = function(){ return ( $scope.share.BuyPrice * $scope.share.Quantity )};
  $scope.share.SellValue = function(){ return ( $scope.share.SellPrice * $scope.share.Quantity )};
  $scope.share.Profit = function(){ return ( $scope.share.SellValue() - $scope.share.BuyValue() )};
}
```